# Ruby idiom for comparison against two values

Tags: ruby

Is there a ruby idiom for something like:

```
a==b || a==c
```

I thought the following should have worked but it doesn't

```
a == b||c
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes I've been known to use `Array#include?` to check for equality against a long list of values.

```
[1,2,3].include? 2 # true
[1,2,3].include? 4 # false
```

But for 2 values, usually the `a == 1 || a == 2` is easier and simpler.

Comment: Keep in mind though, in OP's question, a, b, c are variables, that could be array value. So `[b,c].include? a` is not logically same as `a==b || a==c`.

Comment: @garbagecollection Huh? What values of `a`, `b` and `c` would fail when using `include?`? Even if they are all arrays, that should still work fine.

Comment: Consider a = [1, 2, 3], b = 1, and c = 2. Both a.include? b and a.include? c will return true, but a != b and a != c

Comment: @garbagecollection Are you sure? In both ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 `[1,2,3].include? [1,2]` returns false.

Comment: @garbagecollection No, you have the operands backwards. It's `[valuestolookfor].include? valuetotest` So you'd use `[b,c].include? a`, which under pretty much every scenario I can think of returns the same result as `a == b || a == c`.

Answer (score 1):

`a==b || a==c` is the right way.

Ruby will not support `a == b||c`.

Answer (score 1):

also widely used:

```
[b, c].include?(a)
```